# Combining strings in vector

Tags: r, text, text-mining, rvest

first time posting. I hope you forgive any mistake I might make.

I have to get data from USA Today.
After getting all the paragraphs, I'm kind of stuck because I need to put the 17 paragraphs into 1 piece of text so I can export to a .txt.
Help would be much appreciated

```
USATodayURL <- 'https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/2018/04/05/youtube-shooter-legally-bought-handgun-reloaded-least-once-during-attack-police-say/490969002/'

text_USAToday <- 
  USATodayURL %>% 
  read_html() %>%
  html_nodes('.p-text') %>% 
  html_text()
text_USAToday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `paste`:

```
write(paste(text_USAToday, collapse="\n"), file = "usa.txt")
```

The argument `collapse="\n"` tells `paste` to insert a line break between the elements.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.